# Click on dropdown list in AngularJS for elements other than select using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, dropdown

I'm using Selenium to scrape this [web page](https://www.odepa.gob.cl/precios/precios-al-consumidor-en-linea). In the page I can click on a button and a dropdown list is displayed. I want to be able to select different values from the list in my program.

After a lot of research I found out that normally there is a select element in the html, but this is not the case. I'm certain enough that the element that should be clicked is the following one:

```
<div class="ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-valid ng-touched" ng-class="{open: $select.open}" ng-disabled="form.disabledSemanal" ng-change="getSemanaByYear(form.agno.code, form.fechaTermino)" tagging="" tagging-label="('new')" ng-model="form.agno" style="width: 70px" theme="bootstrap" title="Seleccionar año">
```

Another suspect I have is:

```
<i class="caret pull-right" ng-click="$select.toggle($event)"></i>
```

Which is the little arrow of the button.

I can find both of these elements with the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
url = "https://www.odepa.gob.cl/precios/precios-al-consumidor-en-linea"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
# I have to go through an iframe first
frame_src = "'//aplicativos.odepa.gob.cl/precio-consumidor/serie-precio'"
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//iframe[@src='+frame_src+']')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# Now I find both elements
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-select-container ui-select-bootstrap dropdown ng-valid']")
element2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//i[@class='caret pull-right']")
```

As these elements are not select elements, I cannot use the handy:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
select = Select(element1)
select.select_by_visible_text("Some_value")
```

One solution out there is to use `element1.click()`, but no dropdown list is displayed.

Another solution is to wait to click as in:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='form-control ui-select-search ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-hide']")))
element.click()
```

But I don't get the list displayed.

Am I using the correct elements? How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can use the Select class as the elements you are looking for are not of type Select.

Try this approach, it worked on my end. You have to click the overlay element to expose the input element.

If you go with this approval, replace the horrible time.sleep with webdriver wait and replace the Keys with a better approach

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.odepa.gob.cl/precios/precios-al-consumidor-en-linea')

time.sleep(5)
# Switch
frame = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
           'iframe[src="//aplicativos.odepa.gob.cl/precio-consumidor/serie-precio"]'
        )
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)

time.sleep(2)
tipo_de_serie = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[aria-label="Seleccionar 
                 tipo de serie activate"]'
                )
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', tipo_de_serie)

time.sleep(2)
seleccionar_tipo_de_serie = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('input[aria- 
                             label="Seleccionar tipo de serie"]'
                            )
seleccionar_tipo_de_serie.send_keys('Anual')
seleccionar_tipo_de_serie.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
seleccionar_tipo_de_serie.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: You nailed it. Your `execute_script` approach works like a charm. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help